# "at" command does not run desired program / script

Tags: command-line, kali-linux, at

I am trying to learn scheduling with the "at" command, and therefore, I want to test it out and keep things simple.
For example, when I type `"at 00:28"` (my time zone's format), and then enter `/usr/bin/leafpad`, I expect leafpad to start at 00:28. That does not happen though. Nothing happens, basically.
When I check the related job id with `"at -c jobid"`, the tail of it says "Execution directory inaccessible".

That's pretty weird, because when I type in `"/usr/bin/leafpad"`, leafpad actually opens up.

I am using Kali Linux btw.

Comment: Kali is a specialist pentesting distribution. If you're trying to learn anything outside that remit please don't use Kali, but instead use one of the many more friendly general-purpose distributions. (To be fair, it won't solve the issue you've described here, but it will act more sensibly in other matters.)

Comment: No, the last part of the `at` script tries to `cd` into the directory where you were when you created the deferred task. If it cannot do that, it exits the task with an error status. Your actual command is after that closing brace. `at` does not wrap your commands within any syntax of its own, so that your commands cannot break the script in which it is embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Leafpad is an interactive editor. You will almost never be able to successfully run interactive programs through `at` (or `cron` or similar facilities). There are several reasons for this - the most important one right now is that these facilities are completely detached from, and have no concept of, a user environment. There is no login shell, no PATH variable, nothing that you normally associate with a terminal session.

A better way to start learning `at` is to use the `logger` command, which simply injects a message into the system logs. An example would be:

```
$ echo "/usr/bin/logger 'This is a message'" | at now +10 minutes
```

This command will execute the `/usr/bin/logger 'This is a message'` command 10 minutes after you run it. Using this example, you can then extrapolate further usage of the `at` command and other executables to be invoked by it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification! The only things I'd like to know now:
1. Where can I view that "This is a message" has been successfully logged after those 10 minutes passed?
2. If I can't use `at` with leafpad since it is an interactive program, what could I run instead then? Only a script? Any app I could run that also starts after the time passes?

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact run any valid shell snippet in `at`, and do all the normal redirections. So "What can I run?" is pretty much "Anything that does not require to be connected to a terminal". It would not know which terminal initiated the deferred task, or whether you had closed the terminal, or were now logged out.

`at` creates a large script which contains a snapshot of your environment at the moment that you created the task. (It even includes OLDPWD!) The last line of that script is whatever you told `at` to do. Try this:

```
$ at 2000
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> { pwd; echo $HOME; echo $PATH; env; } >> At.env 2>&1
at> <EOT>
job 97 at Wed Mar  6 20:00:00 2024
$ #.. Show the script just created.
$ at -c 97 | wc -l
55
$ at -c 97 | head | cut -c 1-60
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=1000 gid=1000
# mail paul 0
umask 2
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01\;34:ln=01\;36:mh=00:pi=40\;33:so=01\;35
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe\ %s\ %s; export LESSCLOSE
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8; export LANG
GDM_LANG=en_GB; export GDM_LANG
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=mate; export COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE
GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0; export GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING
$ #.. See the path, and the original command.
$ at -c 97 | tail
PATH=/home/paul/bin:/home/paul/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin; export PATH
SESSION_MANAGER=local/paul-RV415-RV515:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1231,unix/paul-RV415-RV515:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1231; export SESSION_MANAGER
LESSOPEN=\|\ /usr/bin/lesspipe\ %s; export LESSOPEN
OLDPWD=/home/paul/D_Recovery; export OLDPWD
cd /home/paul || {
     echo 'Execution directory inaccessible' >&2
     exit 1
}
{ pwd; echo $HOME; echo $PATH; env; } >> At.env 2>&1
```

The stored script is run under /bin/sh (whatever that links to on your installation). You could of course have `at` run `date >> myAt.log` to confirm it ran at the expected time.

The script that `at` made is run under `sh` (as it has its own shebang), and so is any text that you passed in. But if part of that text executes a script that has a shebang of its own, the Kernel ensures the  script runs under that interpreter correctly.

By contrast, running the same snippet in `cron` gives you a very bare-bones environment.

```
* * * * * { pwd; echo $HOME; echo $PATH; env; } >> Cron.env 2>&1

outputs

$ cat Cron.env
/home/paul
/home/paul
/usr/bin:/bin
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
HOME=/home/paul
LOGNAME=paul
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/paul
$
```

Answer (score 0):

In my system,
`echo mousepad | at now+1 minutes` opens a new tab on Mousepad
only if I have already opened Mousepad.

With Leafpad, nothing happens even if I already opened Leafpad
– apparently Leafpad does not have tabs.

As stated above, `at` is not designed for GUI programs.